# Adding Camera View Inside Custom Keyboard - Swift 3.0 and IOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, camera, keyboard, custom-keyboard

As the title suggests, I am trying to add a camera inside of a view in my keyboard much like the camera inside of the current Messages app.

With my current code, the keyboard just simply gets skipped over when I try to change to it and it never asks for permission to access the camera even though I set the proper key inside of info.plist (I set it in the info.plist for both the Keyboard and the main class). I have written no other code.

This is my code inside of my KeyboardViewController

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

var session : AVCaptureSession?
var stillImageOutput : AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
var videoPreviewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()

    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Perform custom UI setup here
    self.nextKeyboardButton = UIButton(type: .system)

    self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Next Keyboard", comment: "Title for 'Next Keyboard' button"), for: [])
    self.nextKeyboardButton.sizeToFit()
    self.nextKeyboardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleInputModeList(from:with:)), for: .allTouchEvents)

    self.view.addSubview(self.nextKeyboardButton)

    self.nextKeyboardButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    self.nextKeyboardButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    session = AVCaptureSession()
    session!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    let videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    for device in videoDevices! {

        let device = device as! AVCaptureDevice
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front {

            captureDevice = device

        }

    }

    //We will make a new AVCaptureDeviceInput and attempt to associate it with our backCamera input device.
    //There is a chance that the input device might not be available, so we will set up a try catch to handle any potential errors we might encounter.
    var error : NSError?
    var input : AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    do {

        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

    } catch let error1 as NSError {

        error = error1
        input = nil
        print(error!.localizedDescription)

    }

    if error == nil && session!.canAddInput(input) {

        session!.addInput(input)

        // The remainder of the session setup will go here...

        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        if session!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {

            session!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

            //configure live preview here

            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
            videoPreviewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
            videoPreviewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait

            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

            session!.startRunning()

        }

    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    videoPreviewLayer!.frame = cameraView.bounds
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
}

override func textWillChange(_ textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
}

override func textDidChange(_ textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

    var textColor: UIColor
    let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy
    if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.dark {
        textColor = UIColor.white
    } else {
        textColor = UIColor.black
    }
    self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitleColor(textColor, for: [])
}
```

}

Comment: So based on the answer bellow you never got around this, did you? :( I am having a similar requirement and I was wondering if this still applies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to camera from Custom Keyboard Extensions. According to Apple guidelines certain APIs are not available to iOS extensions. Please check out [Appple Extensions guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2) under "Some APIs Are Unavailable to App Extensions".

> Access the camera or microphone on an iOS device (an iMessage app,
>   unlike other app extensions, does have access to these resources, as
>   long as it correctly configures the NSCameraUsageDescription and
>   NSMicrophoneUsageDescription Info.plist keys)

However an iMessage app do have access.

Comment: :( This sucks big time. Is this still the case? (I guess I'm hoping that the documentation is out of date and maybe this changed in the meantime)

Comment: @MihaiFratu still the case with iOS 12.1